Evaluate $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\:\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\left(2n+1\right)!}$. Taylor series, Maclaurin series, or ratio test?
Evaluate the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}.$
I am confused about which series to use for this question. I heard about all three of these methods from my friends, but they all end up different (whether sin(1)-1 or 1-sin(1)). I'm not sure which is true.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions: edit your post to include at the very least what you know about "these three methods", and how you think they could adress the question.

Note that the conclusion of the ratio test (even when it can be applied) is just a single bit of information: the series converges or it diverges. So the ratio test can never help us evaluate the exact value of a series.

Whence my requirement in the previous comment, and my downvote. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121695

Thing we know from prior work, the Maclaurin series for sine:
$$  \sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}  \text{.}  $$
Specializing the $x$ to simplify towards your given series, and popping off the leading term to isolate exactly your series:
\begin{align*}
\sin(1) &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}  \\
    &= \left. \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \right|_{n=0} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}  \\
    &= \frac{1}{1!} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}  \\
    &= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}
\text{.}  
\end{align*}
So,
$$ \sin(1) - 1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}
\text{.}  $$

Perfect answers to poor quality questions encourages them. It is harmful for the site.
